# How to open link from another action?

Tags: jquery

To send a form from another element I use the following:

```
<a data-ref="#" class="checkout" onclick="$('[name=form]').submit();">continue</a>
```

Now I'm trying to do the same but instead of sending a form I want to execute this action (or link) from a tag `<a>`:

```
<a id="checkout some" href="#">Checkout True</a>
```

And I'm wanting to open the link from another point:

```
 <a data-ref="#" onclick="$('[id=some]').click();">Run link Checkout True</a>
```

But it does not work for me :( Of course, I have tried other actions like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunction() {
        $('#some')[0].click();
    }
});
```

From: `<a data-ref="#" onclick="myFunction()">Run link Checkout True</a>`

But it did not work either :(

Comment: Firstly, `id="checkout some"` isn't valid, secondly, you define your `myFunction` inside the `document.ready`, so its likely not going to be available to your button. Best to just attach a click listener inside the `document.ready` for that button.

Comment: @putvande I also tried it without the `document.ready`. but it did not work either :(

Comment: @putvande If two id is not valid, then using a class can also be used

Comment: @putvande This try: https://jsfiddle.net/x1beowjn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
$('#clicked').click(function() {
    $("[id='checkout some']")[0].click()
})
```

I gave an `id` of `'clicked'` to `<a>` which is being clicked.

Also note how I am taking the index like `[0]` before `click()`

You can also achieve the same by making the below change to the code you've written:

```
<a data-ref="#" onclick="$(&quot[id='checkout some']&quot)[0].click();">Run link Checkout True</a>
```

**Note:** Here also I am using `[0]` since its a list of elements